# Cannot share my Ethernet connection anymore after 17.04 install

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet, intel-wireless, 17.04

In Ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10 it worked sharing my wifi through ethernet. In network manager and changed the IPv4 Settings tab, Method: "Shared to other computers"
After upgrading to 17.04 it stopped working, so did a clean install, but still not able to share. My ethernet (wired) connection just turns itself off.
Anyone have a solution?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Currently I'm using manual `iptables` config as a workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Ubuntu 17.04, the dnsmasq-tools dependency has been dropped from network-manager, which results in the network sharing feature failing to work. To fix this, simply install the dnsmasq-base package.

Open Terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq-base
```

This will fix the problem. Information about the bug [can be found here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1678606)...

Comment: @fabby /  Thank you for answer, but since it took awhile for anyone answering I installed 16.04 again, so can't confirm your fix solves the problem. Maybe someone else that tried this can confirm in this thread, and I'll then mark your answer as best answer (solved)

Comment: @sortengel: Blomb answered your question.  I just edited it for clarity.  Since June 15 this answer has received 5 upvoted that it helped other users, so click the little check-mark to mark this problem as [accepted].  **;-)**